# Is it an UB when I try to pass the address of temporary as argument?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

For the following C++ codes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  A() { cout << "A()\n"; }
  ~A() { cout << "~A()\n"; }
  A* get() { return this; }  // <------
};

void f(const A * const &a, const A * const &b) {
  cout << "f()\n";
}

int main() {
  // f(&A(), &A()); // error: taking address of temporary
  f(A().get(), A().get());   // <------
  cout << "end\n";
  return 0;
}
```

And it returns:

```
A() 
A() 
f() 
~A()
~A()
end
```

Of course I can't use `&A()` here because this leads to an error: `error: taking address of temporary`.

But it works when I wrapped it in `A* get() { return this; }`.

So my question is, is it an Undefined Behaviour to use `get()`?

Comment: This is fine. The thing you can't do is use an object that doesn't exist

Comment: It is only UB if the temporary doesn't exist when you use it. When do argument values go out of scope?

Comment: I only use the pointers inside the function. They won't be stored so they won't go out of scope in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is, is it an Undefined Behaviour to use get()?

No, it's not undefined behavior.  It's valid because the temporary object is first constructed, then the function is called, and then (only after the function returns) is the temporary object destroyed again.  So during the lifetime of the function call, you're allowed to do anything you could normally do with the passed-in temporary object, including dereferencing a pointer to it or its contents.  (your function shouldn't store the passed-in pointer for later use, though, since it will become a dangling-pointer as soon as the function returns!)

Comment: Thanks! But in that case, why doesn't C++ just allow `&A()`? What is it for?

Comment: I was wondering that myself.  I think they could have allowed it, but they probably decided that number of instances where a programmer would intentionally want to do that were sufficiently small that it would be better to make it an error, so that the instances where a programmer did it by mistake could be caught at compile time.

Comment: I think that in this case, function `f` should not take parameters by pointers. And thus in properly designed code, one should not need to directly take the address of a temporary.