# Is constructing an object in an argument list and passing a pointer to internal data of the object to the function safe?

Tags: c++, string, temporary-objects

Is the C++ code below well-formed? Will the `std::string` get destroyed before or after the function finishes executing?

```cpp
void my_function(const char*);

...

my_function(std::string("Something").c_str());
```

I know I could do `my_function("Something")`, but I am using `std::string` this way to illustrate my point.

Comment: But seriously, the temporary `string` will die at the end of the expression. That'll be after the function call. So long as `my_function` doesn't store that pointer somewhere with a longer life you're good.

Comment: [Some nearly-canonical documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime).

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find a good duplicate of this. Closest I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875331/is-it-an-ub-when-i-try-to-pass-the-address-of-temporary-as-argument).

Comment: [Here's the canonical documentation](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4) and [some supporting information on when the expression ends](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5). Took longer to find than I thought it would. But go with the stuff at CPP reference. I reads like it was translated from Martian, but in a way that's because it was.

Comment: It's hard to fathom why you propose that construction over simply `my_function("Something");`.  I mean, sure, `std::string` is widely favored over C strings in C++, but when you have a function that wants a `const` C string anyway, how does it make sense to use a `std::string` to make a temporary copy of a perfectly good C string to pass to it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's just an example of a more general case. See the last sentence in the question.

Comment: @Nelfeal Plenty of good duplicates to choose from: https://www.google.com/search?q=c_str+as+temporary+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Will the std::string get destroyed before or after the function finishes executing?

Temporary objects are destroyed (with some exceptions, none relevant here) at the end of the full-expression in which they were materialized (e.g. typically the end of an expression statement).

The `std::string` object here is such a temporary materialized in the full-expression that spans the whole `my_function(std::string("Something").c_str());` expression statement. So it is destroyed after `my_function` returns in your example.